# 「〜がする」 the extended use of する (to do)

Tags: translation, nuances, verbs, syntax

I'm going through some basic grammar and this one website teaches the "extended" use of the word する. There is a confusing example which looks like:

> 波の音 **がする**

The translation is: "(I) hear the sound of waves". The way I learned it prior to this site is:

> 波の音 **を聞く**

What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Xがする is a phrasal verb and is most often used in phrases such as 音がする and 匂い{におい}がする and even 気がする. It is used with words that are about perceiving or sensing something. ([More phrasal verbs here.](http://amaterasu.tindabox.net/guide/AGT.php#phrasal))

Yet it does not really require the actual sensing part from the part of the speaker, but instead is a pretty objective way of saying that 'there is a smell' or '[something] is making a sound'. The focus is less on the sensing but rather just the existence of the sensory input.

波の音を聞く sounds odd to me. It means something like *[I] listen to the sound of waves.* It should be 波の音が聞こえる *I hear the sound of waves.*
With the 聞く verb, it would work as a request such as 波の音を聞いてみて *Try listening to the sound of waves*

Comment: My understanding is that ~がする constructions do not in any way presuppose an experiencer of the stimulus being described. I'd translate e.g. 音がする as 'there is a noise' rather than 'I hear a noise'.

Comment: @Sjiveru You're correct, and I've amended my answer.

Comment: Nothing is odd about 波の音を聞く if one is paying attention to the sound.  It is not logical to state that  波の音を聞く is odd but 波の音を聞いてみて is good.

Comment: I don't think I would personally choose to link to that website, as it appears to be full of errors.