# What does して have to do in [駅を降りたら、どこからともなく美味しそうないい匂いがしてきた。]?

Tags: grammar

Why wasn't it just [駅を降りたら、どこからともなく美味しそうないい匂いが**きた**。] without adding して? What is the role of して in the sentence?

2. that して is supposed to be the 'te' form of 'suru' verb right? What is the closest English meaning of that して in the sentence?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2289/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17850/9831

Answer (score -2):

Do not think of して, the 文法 is 「してくる」 and it implies that something gradually becomes. Like you smell from far away, and it gets stronger

You will also come across many other 「v.-てくる」 examples, but the meaning can vary

たべてくる　＝　to eat before having come
言ってくる　＝　to go and say something (and then come back)
やってくる　＝　to go and complete some task ⇐　this could also be してくる

Comment: what i understood from japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2289/9831 / japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17850/9831 –
is that きた in my sentence is used purely as the verb くる and not as a 'grammatical expression' as you thankfully proposed.
So in my sentence  'the smell came きた!' but 'we don't know from where it came'.

Comment: So the verb here would effectively be 匂いがする、or "to (have a) smell",

The verb is not 匂う, which would be referring to the speakers olfactory ability to perceive the scent. i.e. I can smell it

Comment: My bad! I thought that 匂い is the subject and する is the verb, but it looks like the whole is treated as one verb.
I think what you proposed about きた makes sense now.